# Full Browser Width Bars

Tags: html, css

I have this website:

http://77.104.141.197/~tommasom/otodi/

and I need to achieve this result on the header (blue color full width).

[image]

I tried this solution: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/ but no luck.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code to your CSS:

```css
.header-row {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    z-index:10;
}

html.boxed .body {
    margin-top: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
header {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```